# Create async loop using js

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, asynchronous, puppeteer

I'm trying to implement an async on each loop on nodejs.

I have a variable html which contains the page content. There I want to iterate through all divs that have a particular class. Inside those divs, there are some links that I want to navigate and get some content from them too. So basically since each expects synchronous function it doesn't wait for the other code to be executed.

I tried to do it like this:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
const page2 = await browser.newPage();
const mainUrl = "http ... ";

const html = await page.goto(mainUrl)
    .then(function() {
        return page.content();
    });

await $('.data-row', html).each(function() => {
    const url = await $(this).find(".link-details a").attr("href");
    page2.goto(url)
        .then(function() {
            const title = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerHTML, await page.$('#title'));
            // do other things 
        });
    // do other things 
    // create a json with data add it to a list  

});
```

But the title gives undefined and it's executed after the loop finishes executing ...  What can I do here?

Comment: Are you inside of an async closure?

Comment: You have mixed await and then through all of your code. You can not await a jQuery $().each.

Answer (score 1):

I've edited your code to show how Puppeteer was supposed to be used. Your main problem here was using jQuery where it was not needed and attempting to await things that were not asynchronous; while mixing in a promise chain.

```js
(async () => {

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const page2 = await browser.newPage();
  const mainUrl = "http ... ";

  /*const html = await page.goto(mainUrl)
    .then(function() {
        return page.content();
    });*/
  
  await (page.goto(mainUrl))
  await page.waitForSelector('.data-row');
  const dataRows = await page.evaluate(() =>
    document.querySelectorAll('.data-row');
  )

  /*await $('.data-row', html).each(function() => {
      const url = await $(this).find(".link-details a").attr("href");
      await page2.goto(url)
          .then(function() {
              const title = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerHTML, await page.$('#title'));
              // do other things 
          });
      // do other things 
      // create a json with data add it to a list  

  });*/
  
  for (const row of dataRows) {
    const url = dataRows.querySelector(".link-details a").href;
    await page2.goto(url)
    const title = await page2.evaluate(() => document.title)
    console.log(title)
  }
  
})()
```

Comment: `for (const row of dataRows) { const url = row.querySelector(".link-details a").href;...` I'm getting the error TypeError: dataRows is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

You can't await jQuery.each, to you can try doing the following.

```
const rows = await $('.data-row', html).toArray();

for(const row of rows){
    const url = await $(this).find(".link-details a").attr("href");
    page2.goto(url)
        .then(function() {
            const title = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerHTML, await page.$('#title'));
            // do other things 
        });
    // do other things 
    // create a json with data add it to a list
}
```